# Systemd service B to start after another service A only if Service A exists

Tags: linux, service, systemd

I have two systemd services A and B . I want B to get executed after A but only if A exists else just execute B .

Answer (score 5):

You need to add in your B.service file:

```
After=A.service
```

Or you can add to A.service:

```
Before=B.service
```

From SystemD documentation:

> Before=, After=
>
> These two settings expect a space-separated list of unit names. They configure ordering dependencies between units. If a unit foo.service contains a setting Before=bar.service and both units are being started, bar.service's start-up is delayed until foo.service has finished starting up. Note that this setting is independent of and orthogonal to the requirement dependencies as configured by Requires=, Wants= or BindsTo=.

Documentation source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Answer (score 5):

`SerivceB` needs to include `Wants=` directive for `ServiceA`. `Unit` section of `ServiceB.service` file would look something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=ServiceB description
Wants=ServiceA.service
```

From https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

> Wants= A weaker version of Requires=. Units listed in this option will
>   be started if the configuring unit is. However, if the listed units
>   fail to start or cannot be added to the transaction, this has no
>   impact on the validity of the transaction as a whole. This is the
>   recommended way to hook start-up of one unit to the start-up of
>   another unit.
>
> Note that dependencies of this type may also be configured outside of
>   the unit configuration file by adding symlinks to a .wants/ directory
>   accompanying the unit file. For details, see above.